# Embedded Spring-Kafka makes unrelated unit tests fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

the Spring-Kafka in memory Server is started with a random port. As such the *application.yml* entry is a variable:

```
bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

However, this property is only set when the embedded Kafka server is actually run.
In unit tests without the embedded Kafka exceptions are thrown (because the variable is not actually being set):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'kafkaReceiverConfig': Injection of 
autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
spring.embedded.kafka.brokers' in value "${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}"
```

Here is the Java configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaReceiverConfig {

  @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Bean
  public KafkaReceiver kafkaReceiver() {
     return new KafkaReceiver();
  }
}
```

Inspiration is taken from [here](https://codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html).

Workaround for now is to include the embedded Kafka into every unit test )-;

How can such drastic measures be avoided ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you use an `@EmbeddedKafka` in the test classes, you can do like this:

```
static {
    System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY,
            "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
}
```

So, this way the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` will expose its address with a random port into the `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` directly. Therefore you won't need that change in the `application.yml` and won't need an `@EmbeddedKafka` in other classes.

**UPDATE**

OK! Doesn't look like you rely on the Spring Boot auto-configuration and its conventional properties.

So, to make a `SpringKafkaApplicationTest` working you need to have that system property like this:

static {
    System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY,
            "kafka.bootstrap-servers");
  }

You don't need to have that `kafka.bootstrap-servers` property in the `application.yml` at all.

The problem with the `SpringJmsApplicationTest` that it is fully based on the `@SpringBootTest` which is going to load your `SpringApplication` with all the `@Configuration` classes you have in the nested packages, including `KafkaReceiverConfig` and `KafkaSenderConfig`. I assume you would like do not have them in case of `SpringJmsApplicationTest`. So, you should consider do not load the whole application from your `@SpringBootTest`.

Only a quick solution I see for your tests is like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ActiveMqReceiverConfig.class, ActiveMqSenderConfig.class })
public class SpringJmsApplicationTest {
```

I guess you can do the same for the `SpringKafkaApplicationTest` as well:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { KafkaReceiverConfig.class, KafkaSenderConfig.class })
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
        topics = { SpringKafkaApplicationTest.HELLOWORLD_TOPIC })
public class SpringKafkaApplicationTest {
```

Comment: Unfortunately i can't seem to get it to work like that. Please see repo: [link](https://github.com/Rsmwe/spring-kafkas-tackoverflow/tree/stackoverflow)

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help! Got it working now. [repo](https://github.com/Rsmwe/spring-kafkas-tackoverflow/tree/stackoverflow)